# Use HDMI output on headless system running on RPi4

Tags: hdmi, headless, yocto

I am using Yocto and [`meta-raspberrypi`](https://meta-raspberrypi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to build a Linux image running on my RPi4. I would like to send a video to one of the HDMI outputs, but without running a graphical environment (I don't need a desktop, I just want to send a video stream coming from a webcam to the HDMI output).

It seems to me that `meta-raspberrypi` already brings the graphics drivers, as I have `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` in my `/boot/config.txt`, and my understanding is that vc4 and v3d are the graphics drivers.

My RPi boots normally when I do not plug an HDMI screen to it. But when I do, it gets stuck and loops on output similar to:

```
No EFI system partition
ERROR: invalid device tree
Card did not respond to voltage select! : -110

...


Device 0: unknown device
ethernet@7d580000 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
bcmgenet: PHY startup failed: -110
missing environment variable: pxeuuid
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/01-dc-a6-32-cd-0f-c4
ethernet@7d580000 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
bcmgenet: PHY startup failed: -110
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/00000000
ethernet@7d580000 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
bcmgenet: PHY startup failed: -110
missing environment variable: bootfile
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0000000
```

This also happens if I do not plug the HDMI screen, but set `hdmi_safe=1` in `/boot/config.txt`.

Why would the HDMI screen prevent my system from booting, and what could I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. My RPi CM4 would not boot once I plugged a HDMI device. I was able to fix it by patching u-boot with [this patch](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/uboot/patch/20210512123945.25649-1-m.salvini@koansoftware.com/):

```
diff --git a/board/raspberrypi/rpi/rpi.c b/board/raspberrypi/rpi/rpi.c
index df52a4689f..611013471e 100644
--- a/board/raspberrypi/rpi/rpi.c
+++ b/board/raspberrypi/rpi/rpi.c
@@ -318,9 +318,6 @@  static void set_fdtfile(void)
  */
 static void set_fdt_addr(void)
 {
-   if (env_get("fdt_addr"))
-       return;
-
    if (fdt_magic(fw_dtb_pointer) != FDT_MAGIC)
        return;
```

Now the CM4 boots and I get a display output over HDMI0!